# How can I render data from array nested in object from API in React?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, axios

I am trying to render data from http://www.colr.org/json/color/random.

I use axios to GET data from API. 
When I receive data, i cannot render it trhough the map (because it is obviously an array inside object) so it throws error: 
TypeError: this.props.colors.map is not a function. 
Do I need to use JSON.parse() or what can I do ?

//App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import Color from './components/Color';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    colors: []
  };

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('http://www.colr.org/json/colors/random/2')
  .then(res => this.setState({
    colors: res.data }))
}

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.colors);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <Color 
            colors={this.state.colors}
          />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

---

//Color component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


 class Color extends Component {

  render() {
       return this.props.colors.map((color) => (
        <h1
          key={color.id}
        >
          Color{color.id}: {color.hex}
        </h1>
      ))
  }
}

export default Color;
```

Comment: What is printed in console for this.state.colors ? Isn't this.state.colors.colors.map working?

Comment: how does the response object look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. The data coming back from Colr.org isn't in the format you expected. Use `console.log(this.state)` to see what was retrieved. You mapped over the root `data` object returned. However, the colors you want are nested in the `data.data.colors` array.

Also, take a look at the [Async/Await pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to make sure your JSON data is back from the API before you try to render it.

This should work:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import Color from "./components/Color";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    colors: []
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const apiResults = await axios.get("http://www.colr.org/json/colors/random/2");
    this.setState({
      colors: apiResults.data.colors
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <Color colors={this.state.colors} />
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Wen I get response form API, I get an object with arrays. Does "data" refer to that object, and then what does data.data refers to? to   "data" variable ?

Comment: That was poor variable naming on my part. I set `data` equal to the response from the API. It turns out, the API returned a `colors` object, which contained a `data` object, which contained a `colors` array, which contained your results. Basically, your data was nested in the API results. We had to dig down to the data you wanted (the colors array) using dot notation.

Comment: I just edited my response with better variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON.stringify it will convert it into string or you can use util library it works for me i worked on the same issue last day

Comment: a bit of explaining on en example would be helpful.